# Repo forall reading to file

Tags: bash, repo

I am trying to get out some input into my files. I am doing this

```
repo forall -c  'base=$(pwd);basename $base>names.txt' 
repo forall -c  'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD>branches.txt' 
while read file1 <&3 && read file2 <&4 
do 
echo "This is file1: $file1" 
echo "This is file2: $file2" 
done 3<names.txt 4<branches.txt
```

The problem is that I am getting this error and I cant seem to find it

```
12:58:58 + repo forall -c 'base=$(pwd);basename $base>names.txt' 
12:58:58 + repo forall -c 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD>branches.txt' 
12:58:59 /app/jenkins/workspace/androidTtmp/durable-e0b091fd/script.sh: line 20: names.txt: No such file or directory
```

Could someone see what I am doing wrongly?
I do understand the error message that the file is not there. But why? Isn't the correct way I write the code?

Comment: the error means that the file `names.txt` doesn't exist there